# Data Conversion error 3421 on OpenRecordset method of DAO QueryDef

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to pass one parameter to a saved query in MS Access 2010 and then also get the results from the query: its my saved query:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM tb_KonzeptDaten
WHERE ( Konzept=[fzg_ID] and (DCMFile is null or (DCMFile='')));
```

and here is my VBA code to invoke this query:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
Set qry = db.QueryDefs("Test_qr_emptyDCM")
qry.Parameters("fzg_ID").Value = ID
Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset("Test_qr_emptyDCM")
```

also the Type of ID in VBA code is *Long* and the field of Konzept is Database is *Long integer*
Why do I get this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the `qry.OpenRecordset` statement. The first parameter for `QueryDef.OpenRecordset` is `[Type]` (e.g., `dbOpenSnapshot`). You don't need to provide the query name because you already supplied that when you created the `QueryDef` object.

Try using just

```
Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset
```