# QueryDef.OpenRecordset statement gives "Data type Conversion Error"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, dao

I am trying to use a use a query in MS Access 2010 with an .openrecordset, but it has a criteria that needs to be filled.  I can run this query alone and it uses the open form, but when I try to open it as a recordset, it seems to need a parameter.

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT tbl_equipmst.EquipmentNum, Sum(tbl_equipmentsummary.Miles) AS SumOfMiles
FROM tbl_equipmst INNER JOIN tbl_equipmentsummary ON tbl_equipmst.EquipmentNum = tbl_equipmentsummary.EquipmentNum
GROUP BY tbl_equipmst.EquipmentNum, tbl_equipmentsummary.BatchNo, tbl_equipmst.Z, tbl_equipmst.ZDisabled
HAVING (((tbl_equipmentsummary.BatchNo)=[batch]) AND ((tbl_equipmst.Z) Like "Z*") AND ((tbl_equipmst.ZDisabled) Is Not Null));
```

and here is my code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_Z_Equipment")
qd.Parameters(0).Value = BatchNo
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset("qry_Z_Equipment")
```

But now I get "Data type Conversion Error".  When I debug and hover over qd.Parameters(0).Value I get "3", this should just be an integer.  Is there something I am missing for it you pass the correct type of data?

Comment: @HansUp its a parameter from the sub `Public Sub ZOdometers(BatchNo As Integer)`

Comment: @HansUp The name returns "[batch]" which is the parameter I expect and the type returns 10.  Whatever that means.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the parameter is the cause of the data type error?  Does the query work if you temporarily substitute a fixed value for the parameter ... `tbl_equipmentsummary.BatchNo)=3`

Comment: @HansUp If I remove [batch] from the query and just put a 3, then replace qd with currentdb it runs fine.  But the issue is that I still need to have a variable rather than a fixed number.

Comment: @HansUp Alright I tried something differnt I added 'PARAMETERS [@batch1] Short;' to my query.  Now when I hover over it in debug it is showing correctly without the quotes.  But I still get the same datatype conversion error.  I have then tried different permutations of types like dbOpenDynamic, dbOpenSnapshot but nothing seems to be working.  I suspect now that it is something other that the datatype.

Comment: @HansUp I found it.  from here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234469/data-conversion-error-3421-on-openrecordset-method-of-dao-querydef] dince I was using a querydef, I didn't need to name the query in the openrecordset.

Comment: same answer as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234469/data-conversion-error-3421-on-openrecordset-method-of-dao-querydef